# How to return array of object to ajax call in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I have a php to return data to ajax callback.

```
if((isset($_GET['keyword'])) && (strlen($_GET['keyword']) > 3)){
   $query = "SELECT * FROM bin";
   $result = $db->run_query($conn,$query);
   while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM)){
      $data[] = $rows;
   }      
   echo json_encode($data);
}
```

But when I log it result from it, my data is array of array. I want my return data is array of object.

How to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `mysqli_fetch_object`. It will return  rows as object. You can store those objects in an array.

```
while ($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
    $data[] = $obj;
}
```

`mysqil_fetch_object()` is similar to `mysqli_fetch_array()`, with one difference - an object is returned, instead of an array.